# My aristocratic friend

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, history

I once had a friend. Every second year he wrote me a letter, hoping to receive acknowlodgements for his achievements and developments on behalf of all of human kind.

He was born at an Imperial hospital.

He had three friends. One of them founded Red Cross half-life. Peter and Mary was curious about life.

Once he travelled with another friend to Africa, to commemorate the church founder, singing Hallelujah without 'o'!

Einstein's forefather plays golf.

My friend's favourite object was a brown radio.

In what city did he meet his emperor again?

Hint:

> My friend's birthday is in the 111th period.

Comment: @Gamow If I just tagged it wordplay, science and sequence straight away, it would not been an enigma to the same extent that it became...

Comment: I found this puzzle pretty difficult. (But not as difficult as your Cuba Gooding jr puzzle from last year.)

Comment: Well, I am also not sure that I would have made it through the aristocratic friend puzzle without your strong hints...

Comment: @Gamow My philosophy is that if it is too easy, it's no fun:-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that I now understand most of the puzzle.
I would guess that the answer to "In what city did he meet his emperor again?" should be

> **Vienna** (= **Wien**).

---

### Explanation:

The main theme are

> Nobel prize winners of **physics** in odd-numbered years, starting from the year 1901;
>  this is indicated by "Every second year he wrote me a letter";
>  The puzzle covers 1901, 1903, 1905, 1907, 1909; hence the answer should fall into the year 1911.

He was born at an Imperial hospital.

> Wilhelm Conrad Röntgen; Nobel prize for physics 1901
>  Imperial=**Wilhelm** (Emperor Wilhelm II); hospital=**Röntgen** (X-rays)

He had three friends. One of them founded Red Cross half-life. 
Peter and Mary was curious about life.

> Henri Bequerel, Pierre Curie, Marie Curie; Nobel prize for physics 1903
>  Red Cross = **Henri** (Henri Dunant); half-life = **Bequerel**;
>  Peter=**Pierre**; Mary=**Marie**; curious=**Curie**

Once he travelled with another friend to Africa, to commemorate the church founder, singing Hallelujah without 'o'!

> Philipp Lenard; Nobel prize for physics 1905
>  The Apostle **Philip** is regarded as the founder of the African church.
>  Leonard Cohen sang "Hallelujah"; Leonard without 'o' = **Lenard**

Einstein's forefather plays golf.

> Albert Abraham Michelson; Nobel prize for physics 1907
>  Einstein=**Albert**; forefather=**Abraham**; golf=Phil **Mickelson**

My friend's favourite object was a brown radio.

> Karl Ferdinand **Braun** (brown); Nobel prize for physics 1909
>  Guglielmo **Marconi** (radio); Nobel prize for physics 1909

In what city did he meet his emperor again?

> Wilhelm Wien, Nobel prize for physics 1911
>  German physicist; the first name **Wilhelm** is the name of the German emperor Wilhelm II, the family name **Wien** is the German name of the city Vienna.

My friend's birthday is in the 111th period

> Wilhelm Conrad Röntgen; Nobel prize for physics 1901
>  The chemical element with number 111 is Roentgenium, called after Wilhelm Röntgen.

Answer (score 12):

Partial answer:

This appears to relate to

> Nobel prize winners.

---

> * Though the sentences appear to be muddled, there is reference to Peter and Mary (better know as Pierre and Marie Curie) who researched radioactive elements - hence the reference to half-life - and won the prize for Chemistry.
>  * Einstein won the Nobel Prize for Physics.
>  * Also mentioned is the founder of the Red Cross, Jean Henri Dunant, who was travelling to Solferino to meet Emperor Napoleon III when he witnessed the battle scene that inspired him to set up the organisation, leading to his Nobel Peace Prize.
>  * Albert Schweitzer received the 1952 Nobel Peace Prize. Founded and sustained the Albert Schweitzer Hospital in Lambaréné (now in Gabon). As organist, he influenced the Organ reform movement.